# Wamp missing PHP and MySQL configuration

Tags: php, default-settings, wamp

I have installed Wamp which I used also on other PC. Previous version had full of options to configure PHP, MySQL, PhpMyAdmin like version, extensions. But this Wamp package does not have anything. I don't see any PHP version nor the settings for extensions. What is wrong with that? I download it from https://bitnami.com/download/files/stacks/wampstack/8.0.12-0/bitnami-wampstack-8.0.12-0-windows-x64-installer.exe?with_popup_signin=1#

It should look like:

[image]

But it looks like:

[image]

Comment: WAMP is generic acronym for "Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP/Perl" and may be used by different products offering these (normally separate) pieces of software in a single installation.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the Windows installer according to your first screenshot:

[Wampserver v3.2.3 x64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/wampserver3.2.3_x64.exe/download)

**Edit1:** In the second screeshot you are using **Bitnami WAMP** which is different from **WAMPServer**.

1. WAMPServer is installled with : Apache, MySQL, PHP & phpMyAdmin.
2. Bitnami WAMP is installled also with Apache, MySQL, PHP and PHPMyAdmin.
   Also it contains PHP Frameworks and other modules for several web apps etc...